# Inserting an integer into a list while maintaining descending order

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, homework

> Define a function `g` with two arguments, `w` and `n`, where `w` a list of integers sorted in descending order ands `n` is an integer.; `g` should return a list produced by inserting `n` into `w` in a way that maintains descending order.

For example `g[{9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 6]` must return `{9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1}`.

How cam I do this in the best way in functional programming?

Comment: `g[l_List, n_Integer] := Sort[Flatten[{l, n}], Greater]`

Comment: Hello, the code is doing Map functions and i´m not able to use Sort.

Comment: This is not the answer

Comment: The answer of corey979 does just what you asked... how is it "not the answer"?

Comment: But i cant do the Sort*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Sort` is not allowed then

```
Clear[g]

g[{i : _Integer ..}, n_Integer] :=
 {Cases[{i}, _?(# > n &)], n,
   Cases[{i}, _?(# < n &)]} // Flatten

g[{9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 6]

{9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1}
```

Or

```
Clear[g]

g[{i : _Integer ..}, n_Integer] :=

 Insert[SplitBy[{i}, # > n &], n, 2] // Flatten

g[{9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 6]

{9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1}
```

Or

```
Clear[g]

g[{i : _Integer ..}, 
  n_Integer] :=
 {i} /. {s___, u_?(# > n &), l_?(# < n &), e___} :>
   {s, u, n, l, e}

g[{9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 6]

{9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are three more ways to do it.

```
g[d_List, n_Integer] :=
  Flatten[Insert[SplitBy[d, n >= # &], {n}, 2]]

g[d_List, n_Integer] :=
  Flatten[Insert[GatherBy[d, n >= # &], {n}, 2]]
```

This next is just using `Reap` and `Sow` to do the gathering.

```
g[d_List, n_Integer] :=
  Flatten[Insert[Reap[If[# > n, Sow[#, 1], Sow[#, 2]] & /@ d][[2]], {n}, 2]]
```

For all of these

```
g[{9, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1}, 6]
```

gives

> `{9, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1}`

Comment: Are all of these working in $\log(N)$?