# Inserting an integer into a sorted list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I'm wondering if inserting an integer into a sorted list (in a way that the list remains sorted) can be performed in Mathematica in some fancy way in $\log(N)$ time?..

The question was asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132149/inserting-an-integer-into-a-list-while-maintaining-descending-order), but I'm not sure if any of realizations presented there work in $\log(N)$. I would appreciate if anyone provided the solution for not simply a list, but for a list of lists sorted by their certain element. E.g.:

```
ins[{{1,b},{3,{}},{14,"hi!"}},{6,0}]
```

gives:

```
{{1,b},{3,{}},{6,0},{14,"hi!"}}
```

Where sorting was performed by the first field of the sublist.

Comment: Of course, one could implement a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[insertAndSort]
insertAndSort = With[{a = Join[#, {#2}]}, a[[Ordering[a[[All, 1]]]]]] &;
```

Example:

```
a = {{1, c}, {3, {}}, {14, "hi!"}};
b = {6, 0};
insertAndSort[a, b]
```

> {{1, c}, {3, {}}, {6, 0}, {14, "hi!"}}

Comment: Cool! This is probably exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: `x[[Ordering@x]]` isn't necessarily faster than `Sort[x]` for large lists. **Small test:** With `x=RandomReal[10, 100000]`, average timing for 10k cycles: `x[[Ordering@x]]` = 7.76ms; `Sort[x]` = 4.32ms (on v12.1)

Comment: Thank you @SneezeFor16Min. I removed the remark re timings.

Comment: This is actually slower in a list of say, 1 million elements, than just appending and sorting it, unfortunately ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = {{1, b}, {3, {}}, {14, "hi!"}};
myElement = {6, 0};
SortBy[Join[myList, {myElement}], First]
```

or

```
myList = {{1, b}, {3, {}}, {14, "hi!"}};
myElement = {6, 0};
SortBy[Insert[myList, myElement, 1], First]
```

Comment: "How come I did not come up with this..."

Comment: @mavzolej:  Sorry... *THAT* problem I simply cannot solve!

Comment: I just forgot that Mathematica's built-in sorting algorithm is probably smart enough to work in _at most_  $N\log N$ time, while for a single unsorted element it should be able to work in $\log N$.

Comment: @mavzolej While `Sort` and `Ordering` themselves will might have complexity below $O(N)$, `Join` will have to make a copy of the full old list, so it has complexity $O(N)$...

Comment: Sad news :) Thanks for telling though.

Comment: What about a simple `Insert` (as in the revised solution)?

Answer (score 2):

As it is known that your input list is sorted we could do this with a **binary search**.  As of *Mathematica* 10.1 [I am not aware](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72065/121) of a fast built-in for this operation so I shall use Leonid's code.

```
ins[s_List, x_] := Insert[s, x, bsearchMax[s[[All, 1]], x[[1]]]]

ins[{{1, b}, {3, {}}, {14, "hi!"}}, {6, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{1, b}, {3, {}}, {6, 0}, {14, "hi!"}}
> ```

[Leonid's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2371/121) needed for the function above:

```
bsearchMax = 
  Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {elem, _Real}}, 
   Block[{n0 = 1, n1 = Length[list], m = 0}, While[n0 <= n1, m = Floor[(n0 + n1)/2];
     If[list[[m]] == elem, While[m >= n0 && list[[m]] == elem, m--]; Return[m + 1]];
     If[list[[m]] < elem, n0 = m + 1, n1 = m - 1]];
    If[list[[m]] > elem, m, m + 1]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Comment: Hello, we meet again! I am surprised there is no in built function to do this very fundamental operation fast, as is many times needed.  Would you be able to update your version of bsearchMax to work with the newer and coming FunctionCompile … I am not sure I know how to do it???!!! I am not very familiar with Compile, and was looking also for a fast way to do this … I am investigating CA numbers beyond the 10^7-th if possible, but I can’t even get to 10^6 with what I have now.  I thank you in advance if possible!!

Comment: So, if you use this, with reasonably large lists, it is at least twice as slow as just sorting the list … unfortunately … something better is needed, but I don’t know what that could be.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Introduction**

Since V 12.1 there is `CreateDataStructure`

A link to its many members:
[DataStructures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataStructures.html)

A suitable choice for the question at hand would be [SortedMultiset](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/SortedMultiset.html)

Look under documentation details to see that it works in O(log n).

[what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly?page=2&tab=Votes)

**2. Question at hand**

```
a = {{1, c}, {3, {}}, {14, "hi!"}};
b = {6, 0};

ds = CreateDataStructure["SortedMultiset"];

ds["Insert", #] & /@ a;
ds["Insert", {6, 0}];

ds["Elements"]
```

{{1, c}, {3, {}}, {6, 0}, {14, "hi!"}}

**3. Another example for better visualization**

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["SortedMultiset"];

ds["Insert", #] & /@ Range[1, 30, 2];

ds["Visualization"]
```

[image]

```
ds["Insert", 24];

Normal @ ds
```

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29}

We can insert the same value several times:

```
ds["Insert", 24]

Normal @ ds
```

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 24, 25, 27, 29}

Delete one instance of `24`:

```
ds["Delete", 24] // Normal
```

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29}

Delete all instances of `24`:

```
ds["DeleteCases", 24] // Normal
```

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29}